# CASE statement in WHERE clause to look for multiple values using IN

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

I'm looking to write a SQL statement to report on different rounds depending on the current day of the week.

So if the current day is Monday, I want the report to show me information on rounds 'NOMN','EWM1','EWM2' and 'SOMN' - but if the current day is Tuesday I want the report to show me rounds 'NOTE','EWT1','EWT2','SOTE' and so on for Weds, Thurs, Fri.

Current Code is as follows

```
   SELECT
   insp_route_feat.insp_route_code,
   insp_route_feat.site_code,
   insp_route_feat.plot_number,
   insp_route_feat.officer_code,
   max (inspection_feature.feature_insp_date) as Last_Inspection_Date,

   case
   when  max (inspection_feature.feature_insp_date) >=trunc(SYSDATE,'DD') then 'Inspected'
   else 'Not Completed' end as Assigned


   FROM
   insp_route_feat
   inner join inspection_feature on insp_route_feat.site_code = inspection_feature.site_code and 
   insp_route_feat.plot_number = inspection_feature.plot_number


   WHERE  insp_route_feat.insp_route_code = 
   (CASE WHEN to_char(sysdate,'DY') = 'MON' THEN 'NOMN'
           WHEN to_char(sysdate,'D') = 'TUE' THEN 'NOTE'
                        ELSE null END)

   group by
   insp_route_feat.insp_route_code,
   insp_route_feat.site_code,
   insp_route_feat.plot_number,
   insp_route_feat.officer_code
```

What I would like the WHERE statement to say is something like

```
WHERE  insp_route_feat.insp_route_code IN ( 
   (CASE WHEN to_char(sysdate,'DY') = 'MON' THEN 'NOMN','EWM1','EWM2','SOMN'
           WHEN to_char(sysdate,'D') = 'TUE' THEN 'NOTE','EWT2','EWT2','SOTE'
                        ELSE null END)
```

however I know that coding is wrong, but that hopefully gives an idea of what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean logic makes it far easier than a `case` expression to phrase such logic:

```
WHERE (to_char(sysdate,'DY') = 'MON' and insp_route_feat.insp_route_code IN ('NOMN','EWM1','EWM2','SOMN'))
   OR (to_char(sysdate,'DY') = 'TUE' and insp_route_feat.insp_route_code IN ('NOTE','EWT2','EWT2','SOTE'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use boolean expressions:

```
WHERE ( to_char(sysdate, 'DY') = 'MON' and 
        insp_route_feat.insp_route_code IN ('NOMN', 'EWM1', 'EWM2', 'SOMN')
      ) OR
      ( to_char(sysdate, 'DY') = 'TUE' and 
        insp_route_feat.insp_route_code IN ('NOTE', 'EWT2', 'EWT2', 'SOTE')
      )
```

`CASE` expressions are rarely needed in `WHERE` clauses.  Note that I also fixed the second condition to use `'DY'` instead of `'D'`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, boolean expreasion makes it easier but if you want `case when` statement in `where` clause then there is an option as follows:

```
CASE
  WHEN to_char(sysdate, 'DY') = 'MON' 
       and insp_route_feat.insp_route_code IN ('NOMN', 'EWM1', 'EWM2', 'SOMN') 
  THEN 1
  WHEN to_char(sysdate, 'DY') = 'TUE' 
       and insp_route_feat.insp_route_code IN ('NOTE', 'EWT2', 'EWT2', 'SOTE')
  THEN 1
END = 1
```